# find files not equal to pattern

Tags: macos, find

I want to find all files/dirs that are not equal to `.git*`, so I tried the following commands, but it has the opposite effect (it prints the paths that contain `.git`).

```
$ find . ! -name "*.git"
$ find . ! -name ".*.git"
$ find . ! -name "*.git*"
$ find . ! -regex "*.git"
$ find . ! \( -name "*.git*" \)
```

I also tried the above commands with a `\!` escape, as in `find . \! -name "*.git"`.

**Q:** What's the correct syntax for `find` "not equal to"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Aha! I found it here:

```
$ find . ! -path "*.git*"
```